# What would happen if an Orange Lantern's Central Power Battery was destroyed?

Tags: dc, green-lantern

Is it possible to destroy a Lantern's Central Power Battery, and if you did, how would you remake one?

Answer (score 5):

[image: 7 power batteries]

Several entities now know how to make power rings, power batteries, and even Central Power Batteries since *Blackest Night*.

## Green

Each Guardian of the Universe knows how to make a ring, battery, and Central Power Battery. Natromo of Nok (see Indigo, below), and with him possibly John Stewart and Mogo the planet, now know how to make a Central Power Battery for Will.

Hal Jordan after wearing the Gauntlet of Krona knows how to make power rings and possibly a personal battery as well.

[image: New Central Power Battery​]

## Blue

Ganthet (alone in *Green Lantern: The Animated Series*, with Sayd in the comics) made the first central power battery for Hope, along with rings and batteries.

[image: Ganthet & Sayd]

## Indigo

Natromo of the prison planet Nok, along with Abin Sur (who possibly stole the knowledge from the Guardians on Oa), created the first Indigo Central Power Battery, as well as the rings and staves/staffs of the Indigo Tribe, using water unique to Nok. Natromo later helped John Stewart on Mogo to create a new Green Central Power Battery. Even after the Central Power Battery was created, a pure "spark" of emotional spectrum was needed both times to "start" it.

[image: Indigo Central Power Battery]

Natromo was also in *Sinestro: 5 Years Later* (part of the *Futures End* comics), where he made an incomplete (but operational) Black Lantern power ring for Sinestro out of scrounged parts.

## Violet

The Zamorans of Zamora all know how to make Star Sapphire rings, power batteries, and Central Power Battery from the crystals that grow on the planet they adopted.

The first Star Sapphire power battery encased the crystallized skeletons of the original Hawkman and Hawkwoman; after *Blackest Night*, the Predator, a living entity of the Emotional Spectrum, was used until the "Lights Out" arc with Kyle taking several of the Entities with him beyond the Source Wall to replenish the reservoir.

## Red

Atrocitus created the Rage power rings, batteries, and Central Power Battery as well as the "blood pool" near it. (In *Green Lantern: The Animated Series*, there is only the Central Red Power Battery on Shard, the asteroid-ship, as well as Atrocitus' personal power battery, which Razer stole.)

Atrocitus has shown that he is more than capable of recreating more Red Central Power Batteries and rings as it strikes his fancy.

## Orange

There is only one Orange Central Power Battery in the comics, and it used to house the Avarice Emotional Entity until Kyle Rayner went beyond the Source Wall. There are several hundreds of orange power rings, each one used to manifest an Orange Corps member's stolen entity. (In GL:TAS there was a slightly larger-than-normal personal orange battery as the Central Power Battery.)

No one has been shown creating additional Orange power rings, power batteries, or central power battery. Since Guardian of the Universe Sayd spent several months with Agent Orange, she may be capable of creating orange rings or batteries.

[image: Larfleeze]

## Yellow

A named Weaponer of Qward was the engineer of the yellow power rings used by Sinestro after he was banished by the Guardians of the Universe to the anti-matter universe of Qward. Others on Qward may or may not have this knowledge. At the start of the Sinestro War, Qward was shown mass-producing individual power batteries and power rings, and the Anti-Monitor was shown experimenting on the Emotional Entity of Will on Qward, so Sinestro gained the ability to create his own central power battery, rings, and personal batteries.

This information may or may not be in each Sinestro power ring, but at least three more Fear central power batteries have been shown in the middle of being constructed, both on New Korugar, Qward, and Oa, two without Sinestro being present. Doubtless the Guardians of the Universe could easily make Fear rings/batteries if desired.

The Weaponer has mentioned that he usually needed the power of a G-type star, or an entire inhabited planet of sentient people all in the grip of fear, to make a single ring.

[image: Weaponer making a Sinestro ring/battery]

## Black

Currently the Black power rings come from William Hand of Earth *after* he dies. If you can keep William Hand alive, no more Black rings will be produced.

## White

There is only one White power ring, from the White Entity at the center of Earth, which Deadman wore for a time. Kyle Rayner made a White power ring by combining all the other 7 colors into a White ring.  This has also happened in alternate DC comics. But Kyle lost all the colors except Green when he attempted to resurrect the Blue Lantern Corps on Oa and failed. Some Year Five comics hint at one or two White power rings still existing.

In one issue of the *Justice League of America*, a Green Central Power Battery and power rings were shown being made on Earth in the far future (500 years).

[image: Earth Central Power Battery]

In the JLA of Cadmus in the far future, clones of Guy Gardner (and later Sinestro) were empowered with a power ring. But this ring ran off of their life force, not a battery.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible for a Central Power Battery to be destroyed. The Yellow Lantern Central Battery was destroyed during the [Sinestro Corps War](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Green_Lantern_Vol_4_25).

As for remaking one, it would require control over emotional spectrum power similar to that which was employed in making the destroyed battery in the first place. In the case of the Yellow Battery, [the Weaponers of Qward](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Weaponers_of_Qward) created the original battery with their mastery of technology and deep understanding of fear. Sinestro employed or forced them to create a backup battery before the original was destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** Most of the time, destroying the Orange Central Power Battery would likely "only" result in a very pissed Larfleeze, which you want to avoid. However in 2013, destroying the Orange Central Power Battery would have implied outright killing Larfleeze.

---

Most of the time, if you were to destroy the *anything* belonging to Larfleeze, what you could expect is a very angry Larfleeze coming to fight you, the most likely outcome is you losing and becoming a slave construct. I don't know what could specifically be used to rebuild the battery, but there are ways (see [jhpace1's excellent answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/227444/98028)).

The 2013 *Larfleeze* run offers additional (but probably run-specific) information. In the first issue, Stargrave surmised that Larfleeze had became a power battery himself. He deduced that after seeing Larfleeze using his ring for a very long time without interruption.

[image: Stargrave presents his reasoning to Larfleeze, who unsurprisingly doesn't get it]

In issue #4, Larfleeze is overrun by the newly formed Orange Lantern Corps, former slave constructs of his, who revolt. They notice that their orange rings recharge when close to Larfleeze; thus making him sort of the Orange Central Power Battery. (They keep him alive exactly for that purpose)

[image: Orange mutineers use Larfleeze as a battery]

In this continuity, then, to destroy the Orange Central Power Battery, you'd have had to kill Larfleeze, which would have meant a dead Larfleeze (obviously), and as for a way to remake one, maybe wait for his ring to find a new bearer so greedy, they could become living power batteries in turn.

Killing Larfleeze is something you're likely not going to manage to do, though. Many people tried, few lived to tell the tale, none succeeded.